# Copy between arrays by indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to copy elements of an array (`a`) to a result array `b` according to some rules that define which element from `a` goes where in `b`. I created an example below.

Is it possible (by some smart indexing?) to perform the last step (`b[x,mask] = a[mask]`) in one step for all `x` or can this only be achieved in a loop as shown (in an expanded way) below? `x` in my real example is rather large (~100), so I think this could benefit from a removal of the loop.

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

m1 = a > 6
m2 = ~m1 & ((a < 8) & (a > 4))
m3 = ~m1 & ~m2 & (a > 1)
m4 = ~m1 & ~m2 & ~m3 & (a < 10)


b = np.zeros((4, 3, 3))
b[0, m1] = a[m1]
b[1, m2] = a[m2]
b[2, m3] = a[m3]
b[3, m4] = a[m4]

print '0\n', b[0]
print '1\n', b[1]
print '2\n', b[2]
print '3\n', b[3]
```

Output:

```
0
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 7.  8.  9.]]
1
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  5.  6.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
2
[[ 0.  2.  3.]
 [ 4.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
3
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Since the number `True` elements in each `m#` varies, it's tricky casting this as a single 2-3 dimensional operation.  (they are 3,2,3,1).  You may have to calculate the flattened 1d equivalents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it improves it or not, but it is possible to do the copy in one step if we construct raveled indexes:

Start with a list of the masks:

```
In [1934]: m=[m1,m2,m3,m4]
```

Make an index list by joining the individual list - adjusted to work with a flat or raveled 1d version of `a`:

```
In [1935]: ida=np.concatenate([np.ravel_multi_index(np.nonzero(z),a.shape) for z in m])
In [1936]: ida
Out[1936]: array([6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 0], dtype=int32)
In [1937]: a.flat[ida]
Out[1937]: array([7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 1])
```

Construct the same for 3d `b`, taking into account the different 1st dimension values:

```
In [1938]: idb = [np.ravel_multi_index(((i,)+np.nonzero(z)),bshape) for i,z in enumerate(m)]
In [1939]: idb
Out[1939]: 
[array([6, 7, 8], dtype=int32),
 array([13, 14], dtype=int32),
 array([19, 20, 21], dtype=int32),
 array([27], dtype=int32)]
In [1940]: idb=np.concatenate(idb)
```

Now do the copy:

```
In [1941]: b.flat[id1]=a.flat[ida]
In [1942]: b
Out[1942]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  5.,  6.],
       ...
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

So the copy is done in one call, but I had to use two list comprehensions to construct the required indices.

Comment: Interesting method. Thanks for sharing this idea. I'll see if it improves performance.